# After counting sort the result array has one more element (0) than the original one

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So I have a problem, this method is supposed to sort an array of integers by using counting sort. The problem is that the resulting array has one extra element, zero. If the original array had a zero element (or several) it's fine, but if the original array didn't have any zero elements the result starts from zero anyway.

e.g. `int input[] = { 2, 1, 4 };` **result ->** `Sorted Array : [0, 1, 2, 4]`

Why would this be happening?

```
public class CauntingSort {
    public static int max(int[] A)
    {
        int maxValue = A[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
            if(maxValue < A[i])
                maxValue = A[i];

        return maxValue;
    }

    public static int[] createCountersArray(int[] A)
    {
        int maxValue = max(A) + 1;

        int[] Result = new int[A.length + 1];
        int[] Count = new int[maxValue];

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            int x = Count[A[i]];
            x++;
            Count[A[i]] = x;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < Count.length; i++) {
            Count[i] = Count[i] + Count[i - 1];
        }

        for (int i = A.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int x = Count[A[i]];
            Result[x] = A[i];
            x--;
            Count[A[i]] = x;
        }
        return Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `int[] Result = new int[A.length + 1];` <- You defined your result as beeing 1 longer than A. So it will have 1 extra element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `int[] Result = new int[A.length + 1];` which makes the array one position larger. But if you avoid it, you'll have an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception because you're supposed to do `x--` before using `x` to access the array, so your code should change to something like:

```
public static int[] createCountersArray(int[] A)
{
    int maxValue = max(A) + 1;

    int[] Result = new int[A.length];
    int[] Count = new int[maxValue];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        int x = Count[A[i]];
        x++;
        Count[A[i]] = x;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < Count.length; i++) {
        Count[i] = Count[i] + Count[i - 1];
    }

    for (int i = A.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int x = Count[A[i]];
        x--;
        Result[x] = A[i];
        Count[A[i]] = x;
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Here you go: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##lVLBboMwDL33K3wEUVC7y1SxTUL9g1XaBeWQtWmXjgaUhI6q4tuZSRYKFes6XxLsZ7/nR/b0SMO8YGK/@Vw0DT8UudSwx2xUap5FiZT0pOLJOqNKwZKWQnOxW7Wg8wQwivI942tQmmo8jjnfwIFy4a20RGBKgMqd8i22jdVJaXaI8lJHBSJ0JjzLEenc9nhryahmyxy5mFSm6gn2BYhOyflxupg@1L7vx2ZmPaICgSii8kwDJL6BXCT8lN9oVjJ4hiSdkXjSVbe5bBuBY2kW4/EESZQxsdMf@BUEfoc0s7ZeNwqBKSfDehsDLt7nkkyXUnQAt9H4SrjKmDP3LdnakfgQwLxHb1tfmSozjRjnsVuXxFdIQ9wDuvlX9sFt/3oindAKsWZ42hrU422jCoJhoofEvupSrH@RMbcyTN8tKXYwJ50avAbuCiHMyd9cblcIDeuLNSEM/792GA4T9j@lFene0Z2mXL02O8e9tbppvgE)

Comment: Thanks to everyone and especially you, Piyin, it solved my problem :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :P

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxValue = max(A) + 1;
```

Returns the highest value of A + 1, so your new array with new int[maxValue] will be of size = 5;

The array Result is of the lenght A.lenght + 1, that is 4 + 1 = 5;

The first 0 is a predefinied value of int if it is a ? extends Object it would be null.

Answer (score 0):

The leading 0 in your result is the initial value assigned to that element when the array is instantiated.  That initial value is never modified because your loop that fills the result writes only to elements that correspond to a *positive* number of cumulative counts.

For example, consider sorting a one-element array.  The `Count` for that element will be 1, so you will write the element's value at index 1 of the result array, leaving index 0 untouched.

Basically, then, this is an off-by-one error.  You could fix it by changing

```
Result[x] = A[i];
```

to

```
Result[x - 1] = A[i];
```

HOWEVER, part of the problem here is that the buggy part of the routine is difficult to follow or analyze (for a human).  No doubt it is comparatively efficient; nevertheless, fast, broken code is not better than slow, working code.  Here's an alternative that is easier to reason about:

```
    int nextResult = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Count.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Count[i]; j++) {
            Result[nextResult] = i;
            nextResult++;
        }
    }
```

Of course, you'll also want to avoid declaring the `Result` array larger than array `A`.